# Cant access dot net core application running on ec2

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-ec2, .net-core, kestrel-http-server

Im having issues reaching my .netcore app running on a windows 2016 server instance.

project.json:

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore": "1.5.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "version": "1.1.0",
          "type": "platform"
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true,
    "outputName": "chromagram"
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Program.cs main function:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:6000")
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

[image: When I run the application it works fine.]

[image: When I try to access localhost:6000 on the server its running on, it works great.]

But when I try to connect to the server from any other machine on port 6000 I get no response. (I have added inbound requests on port 6000 to the ec2 security group)

```
.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:6000")
```

This should mean that its listening on all network interfaces, but it doesnt seem to be.

Comment: You could try `http://*:6000`

Comment: @CallumLinington Unfortunately didnt work.

Comment: Did you also open port `6000` in the Windows server's firewall?

Comment: Allowing inbound requests doesn't necessarily open up the firewall too. Not sure as I don't use EC2.

Comment: I can telnet in to the server from my machine on port 6000, so i assume its open

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with EC2 and Mike B's comment above was the fix.  In the AWS Security Group, add TCP port 6000 for your IP (or 0.0.0.0/0 if you don't care about security).  Then, on your Windows Server EC2 instance, go to Control Panel > Windows Defender Fire Wall > Advanced.  Manually add inbound rule for Port > TCP > 6000.  On another server, try accessing your dotnet core app with either http://:6000 and it should work.